# Pandas - resample timeseries with both mean and max

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Given this sample timeseries:

```
                     price   vol
2017-01-01 08:00:00     56  1544
2017-01-01 11:00:00     70  1680
2017-01-01 14:00:00     92  1853
2017-01-02 08:00:00     94  1039
2017-01-02 11:00:00     81  1180
2017-01-02 14:00:00     70  1443
2017-01-03 08:00:00     56  1621
2017-01-03 11:00:00     68  1093
2017-01-03 14:00:00     59  1684
2017-01-04 08:00:00     86  1591
```

> df = df.resample('1d').mean()

gives the mean values and

> df = df.resample('1d').max()

gives the max values but is there a way to get both in a single step?

How do I resample this dataframe such that the output contains the daily mean of the price and volume and the daily max value of price and volume for that day?

Output columns should be index, price_mean, vol_mean, price_max, vol_max and the data should be daily

Comment: You can get many more by using the `.describe()`.

Comment: But that would be a summary and not really what you mean in your question maybe...

Comment: agg will do the job - df.resample('1d').agg(['mean', 'max'])

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [56, 70, 92, 94, 81, 70, 56, 68, 59, 86],
                   'vol': [1544, 1680, 1853, 1039, 1180, 1443, 1621, 1093, 1684, 1591]},
                  index=pd.to_datetime(['2017-01-01 08:00:00', '2017-01-01 11:00:00', '2017-01-01 14:00:00',
                                        '2017-01-02 08:00:00', '2017-01-02 11:00:00', '2017-01-02 14:00:00',
                                        '2017-01-03 08:00:00', '2017-01-03 11:00:00', '2017-01-03 14:00:00',
                                        '2017-01-04 08:00:00'])).resample('1d').agg({'price': ['mean', 'max'], 'vol': ['mean', 'max']})

df.columns = ['price_mean', 'price_max', 'vol_mean', 'vol_max']
```

Output will be like

```
            price_mean  price_max     vol_mean  vol_max
2017-01-01   72.666667         92  1692.333333     1853
2017-01-02   81.666667         94  1220.666667     1443
2017-01-03   61.000000         68  1466.000000     1684
2017-01-04   86.000000         86  1591.000000     1591
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'price': [56, 70, 92, 94, 81, 70, 56, 68, 59, 86],
    'vol': [1544, 1680, 1853, 1039, 1180, 1443, 1621, 1093, 1684, 1591]
}

index = pd.to_datetime([
    '2017-01-01 08:00:00', '2017-01-01 11:00:00', '2017-01-01 14:00:00',
    '2017-01-02 08:00:00', '2017-01-02 11:00:00', '2017-01-02 14:00:00',
    '2017-01-03 08:00:00', '2017-01-03 11:00:00', '2017-01-03 14:00:00',
    '2017-01-04 08:00:00'
])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

df_resampled = df.resample('1d').agg({
    'price': ['mean', 'max'],
    'vol': ['mean', 'max']
}).astype(int)

df_resampled.columns = ['price_mean', 'price_max', 'vol_mean', 'vol_max']

df_resampled.index.name = 'index'

print(df_resampled)
```